# [python]has no attribute 'TessBaseAPI'

Tags: python, tesseract

I got an error when I compiled code blow:

```
import tessercat
api = tesseract.TessBaseAPI()
```

The error is:

> AttributeError:'module' object has no attribute 'TessBaseAPI'

I have already installed `tesseract` via `pip`. The Python version is 2.7 Windows 32bit.

Comment: Michael! I have the same problem on Mac OSX and saw the answers to your question but they were not helpful. Did you solve the problem? If so, could you please let me know what the solution was?

Comment: @MehdiJafarniaJahromi same here..

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to use python wrapper of tesseract (python-tesseract).
Make sure you are using the right version.
You can check this one: [python-tesseract-0.7.6.win32-py2.7.exe](https://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/downloads/detail?name=python-tesseract-0.7.6.win32-py2.7.exe&can=2&q=)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't need to import a sublcass ie `from tesseract import XYZ`

Also - not sure if this was a typo but your import module is misspelled.