# AttributeError:'module' object has no attribute 'TessBaseAPI'

Tags: python, tesseract

With this code :

```
import tesseract

api = tesseract.TessBaseAPI()
api.Init(".","eng",tesseract.OEM_DEFAULT)
```

I have an error:

```
AttributeError:'module' object has no attribute 'TessBaseAPI'
```

Comment: AttributeError:'module' object has no attribute 'TessBaseAPI'

Comment: Possible duplicate: 1. [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30928681/pythonhas-no-attribute-tessbaseapi) 2. [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011534/attributeerrormodule-object-has-no-attribute-tessbaseapi)

Comment: I have checked this link but not solved problem. I have used Raspberry pi-3 please help me..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\[python\]has no attribute 'TessBaseAPI'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30928681/pythonhas-no-attribute-tessbaseapi)